# jquery .each() .load() wait for completion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading rows into a table using jquery and I want to know how I can make them load one by one; i.e. the second block should only start to load once the first has finished loading.

My table looks a bit like this:

```
<table id="dynamicTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading</th>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="1">
  </tbody>
  <tbody id="2">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And my jquery looks a bit like this:

```
$("table#dynamicTable tbody").each(function() {
  $(this).load("filethatgeneratestablerows.php");
});
```

(it's a little more complicated than this as it generates content based on the tbody id and also includes a checkbox system to choose which tbody elements you want to affect, but that all works fine and so I've stripped it down to make my actual question more obvious!)

Comment: You can't use `$.each` if you want them to load in 1 by 1 efficiently (at least, not without a queue-like system). why do you want to load each row individually? that's a lot of requests..

Comment: @Shmiddty: "I want to know how I can make them load one by one" - That's the question. Seems like a pretty straightforward question to me. Looks like all that's needed is an explanation of how asynchronous calls work and how to work around that to get it to do what he wants.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone, I've implemented @user1689607's answer and it's working a treat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var bodies = $("table#dynamicTable tbody"),
    i = 0;

(function loadBody() {
   bodies.eq(i++).load("filethatgeneratestablerows.php", loadBody);
})();
```

This calls load on each index of the collection one at a time. When one load is done, it calls `loadBody` again, using the incremented index.

When `i` is greater than the last one, `.eq()` will return an empty jQuery object, so the sequence will end there.

Comment: Neat. I was thinking of something similar, but your solution is way more elegant.

Comment: This looks like it's what I was after - I'll try it now

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make an array to store the various tbodies. Start with the first and run a load. On complete pass the array with the first taken out. So you pass around like so:

[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4]
[4]
[]

And you keep calling a load function that takes in an array, loads the first element, and passes the remaining elements or breaks on none.

EX:

```
loadElement( $("table#dynamicTable tbody") );

function loadElement( $elements ) {
    $elements.load( "filethatgeneratestablerows.php",
            loadElement( $elements.filter(":gt(0)") ) );
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but I think you should elaborate with a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a

```
$("table#dynamicTable #1").load("filethatgeneratestablerows.php", function(event) {
     $("table#dynamicTable #2").load("filethatgeneratestablerows.php", function(event) {
        ....
     });
  });
});
```

not tested but you should get the point

Comment: as jholloman said you could also store your selectors into an array, iterate over it, and at every complete fire the next .load. Or have a look here for synchronous ajax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re